# apply function returns a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with columns [a,b,c] and other with [a,b,d] as follows:

```
matrix = [(222, 34, 23),
         (333, 31, 11),
         (444, 16, 21),
         (555, 32, 22),
         (666, 33, 27),
         (777, 35, 11)
         ]

# Create a DataFrame object
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))

print(dfObj)



     a  b   c
0   222 34  23
1   333 31  11
2   444 16  21
3   555 32  22
4   666 33  27
5   777 35  11


matrix = [(222, 34, 5),
         (333, 31, 6),
         (444, 16, 7),
         (555, 32, 8),
         (666, 33, 9),
         (777, 35, 10)
         ]

# Create a DataFrame object
dfObj1 = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abd'))
```

I want to take the construct a new matrix with the columns [a,b,c,d] as follows:

```
def test_func(x):
    return dfObj1.d[dfObj1['a'].isin([x['a']])]
dfObj['d'] = dfObj.apply(test_func, axis = 1)
```

However, the output of `dfObj.apply(test_func, axis = 1)` is a dataframe as shown below:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   6.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN 7.0 NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN 8.0 NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN 9.0 NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN 10.0
```

I was expecting the following output - `[6,7,8,9,10]`.

I know that there are several methods to achieve this objective but I am just trying to find out what I am doing wrong in this approach.

Comment: When you do `df.apply(some_func, axis=1)`, it commits "some_func" on every row of "df". In your `test_func` you return a `dataframe` for every function call. And you can't insert the `dataframe` returned from your function into a single column named "d".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if return numpy array with `.values` in function and also add `result_type='expand'` parameter in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def test_func(x):
    return  dfObj1.loc[dfObj1['a'].isin([x['a']]), 'd'].values

dfObj['d'] = dfObj.apply(test_func, axis = 1, result_type='expand')
print(dfObj)
     a   b   c   d
0  222  34  23   5
1  333  31  11   6
2  444  16  21   7
3  555  32  22   8
4  666  33  27   9
5  777  35  11  10
```

Another idea if need return scalar with missing value is use `next` with `iter`:

```
def test_func(x):
    return  next(iter(dfObj1.loc[dfObj1['a'].isin([x['a']]), 'd']), np.nan)

dfObj['d'] = dfObj.apply(test_func, axis = 1)
```

But better/faster is use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
dfObj= dfObj.merge(dfObj1[['a','d']], on='a', how='left')
print(dfObj)
     a   b   c   d
0  222  34  23   5
1  333  31  11   6
2  444  16  21   7
3  555  32  22   8
4  666  33  27   9
5  777  35  11  10
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
dfObj['d'] = dfObj['a'].map(dfObj1.set_index('a')['d'])
print(dfObj)
     a   b   c   d
0  222  34  23   5
1  333  31  11   6
2  444  16  21   7
3  555  32  22   8
4  666  33  27   9
5  777  35  11  10
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function , the result return as `Series`, when you assign it the index do matter , for example , the index 1 will return a Series with index 1 , so it will show in the position as matrix. (apply result will concat, you have different index and columns for each input, like a small dataframe)

```
def test_func(x):
    return type(dfObj1.d[dfObj1['a'].isin([x['a']])])
dfObj.apply(test_func, axis = 1)
Out[48]: 
0    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
3    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
4    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
5    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
dtype: object
```

Eliminate the index impact to fix the out

```
def test_func(x):
    return dfObj1.d[dfObj1['a'].isin([x['a']])].iloc[0]
dfObj.apply(test_func, axis = 1)
Out[49]: 
0     5
1     6
2     7
3     8
4     9
5    10
dtype: int64
```